# How to use GWT UIbinder one inside another

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I am creating a web application in java gwt. I am trying to use one uibinder xml into another. To make things common. Is it possible to do templeting in GWT uibinder so that I can separate my header footer and other common stuff?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You create a widget, which may have as complex Ui:Binder template as necessary. Then you can use this widget inside another widget's Ui:Binder.

In the following example `account` and `w` indicate my own widgets, some of which have their own Ui:Binder templates:

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'
    xmlns:w='urn:import:com.filemambo.core.client.widgets'
    xmlns:account='urn:import:com.filemambo.user.client.account'
    ui:generateFormat='com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.format.PropertiesFormat'
    ui:generateKeys="com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.keygen.MD5KeyGenerator"
    ui:generateLocales="default">

    <ui:with field="constants" type="com.filemambo.core.client.constants.AllConstants" />

    <g:FlowPanel ui:field="container">
        <account:ContactsPanel ui:field="contactsPanel" />
        <g:FlowPanel ui:field="accountPanel" >
            <g:Label text="{constants.payments}" />
            <w:ExtendedDataGrid ui:field="table" checkColumn="false"/>
            <w:ExtendedPager ui:field="pager" />
        </g:FlowPanel> 
    </g:FlowPanel>
```